# how do I change/set the size of text in spinner selection?

Tags: android

I want to change the size of the text that the spinner uses to display the selected item. In other words, I'm not concerned with changing the look/feel of anything when you are actually selecting, just the size of the text that's used once you've selected an item. Sorry if this is confusing, can't think of a clearer way to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `<Spinner>`, define its style:

```
<Spinner
    style="@style/mySpinnerStyle"
    ... />
```

And then define that style and style it the way you want.

```
<style name="mySpinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
</style>
```

Comment: oh, sorry. im creating the spinner programmatically. :)

Comment: Then pass `R.style.mySpinnerStyle` as the defStyle parameter in the Spinner constructor.